# Why does the sun.misc.Unsafe Package Exist

Tags: java, unsafe

I cam across the sun.misc.Unsafe package the other day and was amazed at what it could do. Its existence left me with a few questions.

Is there ever a good reason to use the Unsafe package? Perhaps a more specific question would be, what scenario could arise that you would need it. If you do need it, does that not spell out that something is probably wrong with your design? Why is it even included?